# «Подобно миражу». Запятая нужна?

Tags: запятые

В предложении: «Подобно миражу возникают на фоне неба островерхие башни замка». Нужна ли запятая? В начале предложения и если в конце предложения стоит «подобно чему-то», стоит ли ставить запятую?
«При оборотах с предлогом «подобно» запятая нужна, если этот оборот можно переставить; чаще всего в тех случаях, если он находится между подлежащим и сказуемым». А если «подобно» стоит в начале и конце предложения, не в середине?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Я полагаю, что оборот не обособляется аж по двум причинам: он стоит в начале предложения и он часть сказуемого.**

1. Оборот с "подобно" обособляется, [если стоит **не** в начале и **не** в конце предложения](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1).
2. В данном же конкретном случае, как мне кажется, оборот входит в сказуемое, но инверсирован. Я думаю, прямой порядок слов в предложении подразумевается такой: *На фоне неба островерхие башни замка возникают подобно миражу.* Как видите, в таком случае нельзя отсечь "подобно миражу" без того, чтобы *"возникают"* не повисло обрывком сказуемого. Следовательно, и при инверсии запятая не требуется.

Comment: Вот я так и думала...

Answer (score 0):

***Подобно миражУ** /возникают на фоне нЕба // островерхие башни зАмка.*

***Подобно миражу*** – обстоятельственный оборот в начале предложения, он выражен падежной формой существительного.

В данном случае он **не обособляется** и является детерминантом, то есть относится ко всему составу предложения.

Обстоятельственные обороты часто встречаются **именно в такой позиции**, но обособляются только при их актуализации (подчеркивании логическим ударением). В данном случае предложение **простое**, все паузы в нем **произносительные.**

В общем случае обособление обстоятельственных оборотов факультативно и по правилу Розенталя зависит **от ряда факторов**.

В состав сказуемого оборот не входит, так как глагол "возникать" **нельзя отнести к знаменательным связкам.**

**Для справок:**

**Связка** выражает значения времени и модальности (предикативность), а также различные модально-оценочные значения (наличия, становления, проявления, обнаружения признака).

Типы связок:

1. **незнаменательная**: глагол быть (в наст, времени имеет нулевую форму);
2. **полузнаменательная**: являться, делаться, стать, становиться, казаться, оказаться, показаться, считаться, слыть, называться, превратиться в, оставаться, притвориться, получаться, выходить и др.; в качестве полузнаменательных связок употребляются
   также описательные обороты иметь (носить) характер; приобретать вид (характер, положение);
3. **знаменательная** — глаголы движения и положения (прийти,
   наступить, стоять и др.): пришел (усталый), вернулся (генералом),
   лежал (больной), спал (одетый)

[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)  стр.72

Comment: Там в справочнике ниже написано: *В связочной функции глагол меняет значение по сравнению с
автономным употреблением, сравним: На дороге показался всадник (ПГС) — Он показался мне усталым (СИС)*. Возможно, глаголу "возникнуть" это тоже свойственно?

Comment: Он показался мне усталым.  Это СИС, связка полузнаменательная (значение восприятия: был/показался усталым). Обратите внимание на двойную связь: именная часть согласуется с подлежащим и управляется глаголом (Т.п.). Это совсем другая структура по сравнению с приведенным предложением.

Comment: Я недостаточно в теме разбираюсь, чтобы дискутировать, но мне всё же кажется, что мой ответ не ошибочен в той части, что про сказуемое.

Comment: Ну, я тоже могу ошибаться...  Вот и плохо, что все молчат, а мы с вами вдвоем отвечаем. (Вы-то хотя бы не пропадайте. ) Конечно, мне интересно было бы услышать еще чье-нибудь мнение.